# zf2 and ajax I can't get the parametrs

Tags: ajax, jquery, zend-framework2

I can not get the data passing from the controller ajax me there any solution?
button click action

```
$(".bajaAlumno").click(function () {
    var urlform = "<?php echo $this->url(null, array('controller'=>'Academius','action'    =>'bajaAlumnos' ) ); ?>";
    var dato= $(this).attr('id');
    var myData = {textData:dato};

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/Academius/bajaAlumnos",
        data:{data:myData},
        success: function(data){
            //The callback function, that is going to be executed 
            //after the server response. data is the data returned
            //from the server.

            // Show the returned text
            //$("#answer").text(data.text);
            //$("#answer").text(data.text);
            alert('enviado');
        }
    });
});
```

and controller

```
public function bajaAlumnosAction()
{
    die(var_dump($this->params()->fromPost()));   
}
```

one answer?

Comment: What is the result of the ajax call if you inspect? If the call even firing? It would be useful for your debugging if you added a `error` callback to see what is being returned

Comment: Try setting dataType: 'json' in your ajax call

Comment: If you're using json, are you adding success => true to your json object?

Comment: Is not your named action ? **bajaalumnosAction** instead **bajaAlumnosAction**